# Custom Toolbar UIBarButtonItem images - What am i doing wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

here is the code:

http://pastebin.com/zQXmYgzJ

It crashes at runtime at the line:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:toolbarItems]autorelease];
```

with the error

> "'-[UIBarButtonItem isEqualToString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x4b2e780'"

I can't understand this error message... everything seems to be fine as in the debugger i can see that a 3 object array of bar buttons is being passed to segmented control... does anyone have an idea why I am hitting runtim errors here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass in an array of UIBarButtonItems, only NSString or UIImage:

> initWithItems: Initializes and returns
>   a segmented control with segments
>   having the given titles or images.
>
> - (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)items Parameters items An array of *NSString*
>     objects (for segment titles) or
>     *UIImage* objects (for segment images).

Comment: Thank you, this is correct and I apologize for wasting anyone's time. :)